# Optimize Hibernate HQL SELECT with IN clause

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

Please how can I optimize this query?

```
FROM OrderEntity WHERE id IN (SELECT DISTINCT orderId FROM ProductEntity 
  WHERE code = :myCode OR extCode = :myCode)
```

This query is too slow for the tables which has around million rows

Order 1 ... * Product

Thank you for help

**EDIT**

In pure sql I would use this query which is fast, but I don't know how to form it in HQL:

```
SELECT * FROM order o, (SELECT DISTINCT order_id FROM product WHERE code = 'ABC' 
   OR ext_code = 'ABC') p WHERE o.id = p.order_id
```

Comment: Did you try database performance tools? It is most probably not a HQL issue, but a "regular" database performance issue. (Indexes etc.)

Comment: don't use DISTINCT in <IN> clause

Comment: FROM OrderEntity WHERE id IN (SELECT orderId FROM ProductEntity 
  WHERE code = :myCode UNION ALL SELECT orderId FROM ProductEntity  extCode = :myCode)           try this solution

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it is still too slow. Almost the same time like in query in my post

Comment: what about index on  fields: code, extCode

Comment: may be  SELECT o.* FROM order o INNER JOIN (SELECT order_id FROM ProductEntity WHERE code = :myCode UNION ALL SELECT orderId FROM ProductEntity extCode = :myCode) p ON o.id = p.order_id

Comment: indexes are ok .. I think problem is in IN clause .. will check your last query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that ProductEntity can be mapped with an association to OrderEntity (Foreign key order_id) .

If true, try to map it and test this query (inner join may be faster)  :

```
SELECT o 
FROM
ProductEntity p 
INNER JOIN p.orderEntity o 
WHERE p.code = :myCode OR p.extCode = :myCode
```